# processing output encoding different from Java.io encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, processing

I have no java experience and I am just starting to experiment with Processing.

I am trying write a script in processing which will send a 512 byte array using a http post command to a web server. This is all working well (thanks to code I dug up on the internet!) but I am having some trouble with the encodings. I am creating a character array filled with 0xFF. This prints as 512 'ÿ' characters in the output window as it should. The issue is HTTPScoop shows the post hex as a series of 0xD8 characters or the 'Ø' character. I am unsure why the console is printing one character and the output stream seems to be sending another.

Code below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    // Construct data
    char[] anArray = new char[512];
    char charFillValue = 0xFF;
    Arrays.fill(anArray, charFillValue);

    String str = new String(anArray);
    println(str);

    String data = str;
    println(data);

    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("http://10.10.155.120:8081/set.cgi?dst=p1");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
} 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {}`  Don't ignore exceptions in broken code!  That should be `catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}`.  (It is not the immediate problem, but fix it anyway.)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, exceptions no longer ignored! (There are currently no exceptions in the above snippet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem seems to be that Java's default encoding and the encoding of the server do not match.  Set an encoding in the `OutputStreamWriter`.  E.G. using the [`OutputStreamWriter(OutputStream,encoding)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor.

Comment: Fantastic! It looks like it is ISO encoding!  thanks for your help!  new code is: OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "ISO8859_1");